# How to change CSS theme in GWT at run time?

Tags: css, gwt

There are few solutions in SO regarding this , but non relates to my situation .

I have a separate css files in my war folder.

w3-theme-blue.css   in my war folder

w3-theme-red.css    in my war folder.

Now if i want to load blue theme, i write this  in my project.html file

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/w3-theme-blue.css">
```

if i want to load red theme, i write this  in my project.html file

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/w3-theme-red.css">
```

Now what i want to achieve is to change from blue to red or vice versa at Run Time.

I checked this one in javascript

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

used this with jsni , but no luck

then i try to implement the same code in GWT , like this

```
     Element s = DOM.createElement("link");
    s.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    s.setAttribute("href", "w3-theme-red.css");
    DOM.getElementById("body").appendChild(s);
```

But , still no luck ...

Please guide..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to load the stylesheet dynamically then use JSNI

```
private native void loadCSS (String cssHref) /*-{
  $doc.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' +
cssHref + '">');
}-*/
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says 
document.wrtie is not a function, any suggestion

Comment: edited the response ...please check the GWT JSNI syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use `StyleInjector`:

```
// safe your StyleElement that is returned with injectStyleSheet()
// so you can override it later with a new style
public static StyleElement content;

[...]  

CssResource style =  GWT.create(CssBundle.class);
content = StyleInjector.injectStylesheet(style.css1().getText());
```

To replace your style with another you can do this:

```
  // overrides the content, that you defined before with your second theme
  StyleInjector.setContents(content, style.css2().getText());

  // setContents docu says that it might not work as expected in IE...
  // maybe you have to use inject() then and delete the old style,
  // otherwise you are adding more and more styles after each theme change  

  // StyleInjector.inject(style.css2().getText());
```

I hope this gets you going...